# Building complex querysets using Model Manager in Django returning empty queryset

Tags: django

Am trying to build a complex queryset whereby am joining with other tables. What is buzzling me here is that am able to see the query when i print the queryset.query but as i call it from my code its returning no result.

```
class CarManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(CarManager, self).get_query_set().filter(version_to__isnull=True)

    def my_cars(self, language, user):

        qs=self.extra(
            select = {
                'make_display' : '`%s`.`%s`' % (ModelLookUpI18n._meta.db_table, ModelLookUpI18n._meta.get_field('make_display').column),
                'model_display' : '`%s`.`%s`' % (ModelLookUpI18n._meta.db_table, ModelLookUpI18n._meta.get_field('model_display').column),
                'trim_display'  : '`%s`.`%s`' % (ModelLookUpI18n._meta.db_table, ModelLookUpI18n._meta.get_field('trim_display').column),
                },
            tables = [
                '`%s`' % ModelLookUpI18n._meta.db_table,
            ],
            where = [
                '`%s`.`%s` = `%s`.`%s`' % (ModelLookUpI18n._meta.db_table, ModelLookUpI18n._meta.get_field('model').column, ModelLookup._meta.db_table, ModelLookup._meta.get_field('id').column),
                "`%s`.`%s`='%s'" % (ModelLookUpI18n._meta.db_table, ModelLookUpI18n._meta.get_field('language').column, language)
            ]
        ).select_related().filter(created_by=user).order_by('-created_at')

        print qs.query # prints the SQL statement
        print qs # always prints []
        return qs
```

When I copy the query printed in the console and paste it into mySQL terminal I 21 records and it looks very normal to me. Yet, the queryset is always empty, any ideas on how to debug further?

Oh, I even monitored the MYSQL execution log to make sure what is going to the engine is matching what is printed by qs.query and its the same.

Comment: Interresting, did you try to paste the query in `manage.py dbshell` ? That would find out if it's a permission problem I guess.

Comment: i found the problem, when i the alias name cannot be the same name as the field in the select params. I had to replace "make_display" with "make_i18n" for example in order for it to work