# AJAX call taking a long time (2-4 secs)

Tags: ajax, django

I'm really stumped on an issue. On my website, whenever you pan the map, an AJAX call is fired, doing a query in the database. The problem is, the AJAX call takes somewhere between 2-10 seconds, which is unacceptable.

[Link to website](https://www.bungol.ca/map/?)

There are about 500k records in my database. I notice that the more records I add, the slower it gets. That makes sense right, but why is it exceptionally slow and so inconsistent?

I am using Digital Ocean. When I check my control panel, the CPU/RAM/disk are all operating at very low levels.

The AJAX  call code:

```
def filter_closed_listings(request):
    zoom = int(request.GET.get('zoomLevel'))
    minLat = request.GET.get('minLat')
    maxLat = request.GET.get('maxLat')
    minLng = request.GET.get('minLng')
    maxLng = request.GET.get('maxLng')

    sold = request.GET.get('sold')
    property_type = request.GET.get('pType')
    building_style = request.GET.get('bType')
    showActiveListings = request.GET.get('showActiveListings')
    showSoldListings = request.GET.get('showSoldListings')
    showEndedListings = request.GET.get('showEndedListings')
    bed = request.GET.get('bed')
    bath = request.GET.get('bath')
    low_price = request.GET.get('low')
    high_price = request.GET.get('high')
    includePandL = request.GET.get('includePandL')
    transaction_type = request.GET.get('transactionType')

    ended_time_difference = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(-int(sold)) # Date check
    print(ended_time_difference)
    # Initial filter with map bounds and date check
    data = Listing.objects.filter(la__gt=minLat).filter(la__lt=maxLat).filter(lo__gt=minLng).filter(lo__lt=maxLng)

    data = data.filter(transaction_type=transaction_type)

    # 0 is 'Any'.  Therefore a filter is done if selection is not 'Any'.
    if not property_type == '0':
        if property_type == '1':
            data = data.filter(Q(property_type='Condo Apt') | Q(property_type='Comm Element Condo'))
        elif property_type == '2':
            data = data.filter(property_type='Detached')
        elif property_type == '3':
            data = data.filter(property_type='Semi-Detached')
        elif property_type == '4':
            data = data.filter(Q(property_type='Att/Row/Twnhouse') | Q(property_type='Condo Townhouse'))
        else:
            data = data.exclude(Q(property_type='Condo Apt') | Q(property_type='Comm Element Condo') | Q(property_type='Detached') | Q(property_type='Semi-Detached') | Q(property_type='Att/Row/Twnhouse') | Q(property_type='Condo Townhouse'))

    if showActiveListings == 'n':
        data = data.filter(Q(status='Ter') | Q(status='Exp') | Q(status='Sld') | Q(status='Lsd'))

    if showSoldListings == 'n':
        if transaction_type == 'Sale':
            data = data.exclude(status='Sld')
        else:
            data = data.exclude(status='Lsd')
    else:
        if transaction_type == 'Sale':
            data = data.exclude(Q(status='Sld') & Q(sold_date__lt=ended_time_difference))
        else:
            data = data.exclude(Q(status='Lsd') & Q(sold_date__lt=ended_time_difference))

    if showEndedListings == 'n':
        data = data.exclude(Q(status='Ter') | Q(status='Exp'))
    else:
        data = data.exclude(Q(status='Exp') & Q(expiry_date__lt=ended_time_difference)).exclude(Q(status='Ter') & Q(terminated_date__lt=ended_time_difference))

    if includePandL == 'false':
        data = data.exclude(Q(property_type='Parking Space') | Q(property_type='Locker'))
    # Bedrooms check
    if not bed == 'undefined':
        bed = bed.split(',')

        queries = [Q(bedrooms_ag=b) for b in bed]
        query = queries.pop()
        if bed.pop() == '6':
            query = Q(bedrooms_ag__gte=5)
        for i in queries:
            query |= i
        #print(query)
        data = data.filter(query)

    # Bathrooms check
    if not bath == 'undefined':
        bath = bath.split(',')

        queries = [Q(washrooms=b) for b in bath]
        query = queries.pop()
        if bath.pop() == '6':
            query = Q(washrooms__gte=5)
        for i in queries:
            query |= i
        #print(query)
        data = data.filter(query)

    # Filters low price and high price
    if high_price == '0' and low_price == '0':
        pass
    elif high_price =='0':
        data = data.filter(Q(Q(list_price__gte=low_price) & Q(list_price__lte=999999999) & Q(sold_price__isnull=True)) | Q(Q(sold_price__gte=low_price) & Q(sold_price__lte=999999999) & Q(sold_price__isnull=False))) # Nested Q object.  Use list price if sold price is null.
    else:
        data = data.filter(Q(Q(list_price__gte=low_price) & Q(list_price__lte=high_price) & Q(sold_price__isnull=True)) | Q(Q(sold_price__gte=low_price) & Q(sold_price__lte=high_price) & Q(sold_price__isnull=False)))

    if data.count() > 500:
        return JsonResponse({'over500': True})
    data = data.values('id', 'la', 'lo')
    # Determines lat/lng precision based on zoom level
    for i in data:
        if zoom >= 13:
            i['lo'] = round(i['lo'], 4)
            i['la'] = round(i['la'], 4)
        elif zoom > 9 and zoom < 13:
            i['lo'] = round(i['lo'], 2)
            i['la'] = round(i['la'], 2)
        else:
            i['lo'] = round(i['lo'], 1)
            i['la'] = round(i['la'], 1)



    return JsonResponse({'results': list(data)}) # This uses list() which is bad design.  But only 3 fields are passed and highly unlikely to change so this can stay like this.
```

Comment: This really depends on how the data is being returned and how efficient your underlying queries are to your database.  You should test the requests outside of the AJAX scope - this will help you isolate where the bottleneck is.

Comment: I know nothing about Django, but each `data = data.filter(...)` or `data = data.exclude(...)` seems to require a database query or other processing of a large data set. Can all your conditions be [batched up into a single query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24142244/1270789)?

Comment: @KenY-N  just for info - Django ORM is lazy so until data is set to retrieval no queries will be fired.

Comment: @Jack following looks like bunch of different filters from which Query is built upon.  You should profile your view and analyze underlying query to check out which indexes you could potentially set on your table to improve Query execution

Comment: @iklinac [This answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24008103/1270789) one should avoid chaining as there still is a large overhead to clone each step of the way, so `Listing.objects.filter(la__gt=minLat).filter(la__lt=maxLat).filter(lo__gt=minLng).filter(lo__lt=maxLng)` should become `Listing.objects.filter(la__gt=minLat, la__lt=maxLat, lo__gt=minLng, lo__lt=maxLng)` or similar. I agree with your other comment about indices.

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments.  I've added `db_index=True` to all fields that may be queried.  Performance is still not optimal.  There seems to be a 10x multipler between development and production environements (400ms ajax call on development server takes about 4 sec in production).  @KenY-N I'm going to try your recommendation and see if that helps